# Paging property missing in Status

Tags: linq-to-twitter

In latest version of LINQ to Twitter v2.1.08 there is no longer support for paging. How do I get a certain page without page property?

Cheers

```
int curPageIndex=5;
string pageindex="5";
string cmd = "next";
using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(myauth))
  {
    try
    {
      // set up the "main query"
      IQueryable<Status> test = from tweet in twitterCtx.Status select tweet;


      switch (cmd)
      {
        case "prev":

          test = pageindex.Length > 0
                   ? test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home && p.Page == curPageIndex)                       
                   : test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home);
          break;
        case "next":
          test = pageindex.Length > 0
                   ? test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home && p.Page == curPageIndex)                       
                   : test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home);
          break;
        default:              
          //
          test = test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home);
          break;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Changed Page parameter to SinceID and MaxID

```
//Get the statusids in the query, add or subtract so you skip current id's
ulMaxId = test.Min(status => ulong.Parse(status.StatusID)) - 1;
ulSinceID = test.Max(status => ulong.Parse(status.StatusID)) + 1;

//Return ID above and use them in future calls (below)

//Now you can navigate timelines, depending if you are stepping forward or backwards

? test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home && p.SinceID == ulong.Parse(sinceid)
...
? test.Where(p => p.Type == StatusType.Home && p.MaxID == ulong.Parse(maxid))
```

Comment: Twitter API v1.1 removes the page parameter, in favor of since_id and max_id. You might have seen this, but I'll post it in case anyone else has the same issue - Working with Timelines with LINQ to Twitter: http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2012/09/02/working-with-timelines-with-linq-to-twitter.aspx